# How to add angular material in Angular ~4.3.3

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm getting the following error when I use `@angular/material` and `@angular/cdk`:

> `http://localhost:3000/@angular/cdk/observe-content (404) Not found error`

`systemjs.config.js`

```js
map: {
       ...

    // Angular Material 
    '@angular/material': 'npm:@angular/material/bundles/material.umd.js',

    // CDK individual packages
    '@angular/cdk/platform': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-platform.umd.js',
    '@angular/cdk/a11y': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-a11y.umd.js',
}
```

`materialmodule.ts`

```ts
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { MdButtonModule, MdCheckboxModule,MdButton } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        MdButtonModule,
        MdButton
    ],
    exports: [
        MdButtonModule,
        MdButton
    ]
})
export class CustomMaterialModule { }
```

`app.component.ts`

```ts
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import {CustomMaterialModule} from './materialmodule/material.module';
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        CustomMaterialModule
    ],
    declarations: [ AppComponent ],
    bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

What is missing from my code that causes the error as stated above?

Comment: Did you try adding `'@angular/cdk/observe-content': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-observe-content.umd.js'` to your systemjs config?

Comment: Why do you have duplicate of `MdButtonModule` in your module??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By the looks of it, you need to add the `cdk/observe-content` entry to your `systemjs.config.js`. Here is a list of packages they serve, doesn't hurt adding them just to be safe. It is weird though that their documentation only says to add `platform` and `a11y`, but I suppose depending on what kind of material module you use, you have to import a certain `cdk`:

```
'@angular/material': 'dist/bundles/material.umd.js',
'@angular/cdk': 'dist/bundles/cdk.umd.js',
'@angular/cdk/a11y': 'dist/bundles/cdk-a11y.umd.js',
'@angular/cdk/bidi': 'dist/bundles/cdk-bidi.umd.js',
'@angular/cdk/coercion': 'dist/bundles/cdk-coercion.umd.js',
'@angular/cdk/keyboard': 'dist/bundles/cdk-keyboard.umd.js',
'@angular/cdk/observe-content': 'dist/bundles/cdk-observe-content.umd.js',
'@angular/cdk/platform': 'dist/bundles/cdk-platform.umd.js',
'@angular/cdk/portal': 'dist/bundles/cdk-portal.umd.js',
'@angular/cdk/rxjs': 'dist/bundles/cdk-rxjs.umd.js',
'@angular/cdk/table': 'dist/bundles/cdk-table.umd.js',
'@angular/cdk/testing': 'dist/bundles/cdk-testing.umd.js',
```

If you are just going to use your `CustomMaterialModule` as a barrel you should just export the modules you need (not the components), no need to import them:

```
@NgModule({
  exports: [
    MdButtonModule
  ]
})
export class CustomMaterialModule {}
```

Comment: Yes it requires other packages too. Quick question: Does my MaterialModule require any MaterialCore package or any other default package ??? It still gives me error there.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, everything should be inside `material.umd.js`. What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: `Unexpected directive 'MdButton' imported by the module 'CustomMaterialModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.`

Comment: Well, you should not import `MdButton`, you should only export its module `MdButtonModule`. I'll update my answer a bit

Comment: @micronyks Why are you using a duplicate of `MdButtonModule`?

Comment: i use the angular 6 and i dont have systemjs.config.js what can i do 
it say cdk-a11y.umd.js is  missing

Answer (score 2):

Version for angular 4.3

```
        '@angular/cdk': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk.umd.js',
        '@angular/cdk/a11y': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-a11y.umd.js',
        '@angular/cdk/bidi': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-bidi.umd.js',
        '@angular/cdk/coercion': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-coercion.umd.js',
        '@angular/cdk/collections': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-collections.umd.js',
        '@angular/cdk/keycodes': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-keycodes.umd.js',
        '@angular/cdk/observers': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-observers.umd.js',
        '@angular/cdk/overlay': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-overlay.umd.js',
        '@angular/cdk/platform': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-platform.umd.js',
        '@angular/cdk/portal': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-portal.umd.js',
        '@angular/cdk/rxjs': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-rxjs.umd.js',
        '@angular/cdk/table': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-table.umd.js',
        '@angular/cdk/scrolling': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-scrolling.umd.js',
```